# How to apply additional styles to a StyledMapType (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Map with all the default map types plus a few of my own StyledMapTypes. At runtime, I want to be able to toggle the different Road types on and off, and have it apply to all the MapTypes. If I set the MapOption style property, it applies to the default map types only. And there is no way to access or change the MapTypeStyles of the StyledMapType other than the constructor.

Is there any way to do this other than creating a new StyledMapType for each combination of StyledMapType and Road/Highway configuration?

This method does not scale well: 
2 Styled Maps * 2 Local Road states * 2 Highway states * 2 Arterial Road states = 16 StyledMapTypes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set styles via `map.setOptions({ 'styles': styles });`
See documentations on MapOptions: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#MapOptions

Here is a rather complete example:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html
(see the setMapStyle-function in http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/StyledMapWizard.js)

This tool may also help to style your maps more easly.

Comment: As stated in my question, setting styles on the map only applies to the default map types. I also need to further style the StyledMapType maps types.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `StyledMapType` is immutable. Please file a feature request :-)

Comment: I've done that already. Hoping to find a more elegant workaround than the one I've described above.